# System can't find the python folder

Tags: python, cmd

Before you say anything,yes i have python path set.Everytime when i type 'cd Python37' it says that the system can't find the path specified.Is it because im using the python 3.7.2 or is the path set wrong (i accidentaly installed in the non-default folder,still im a beginner).

Comment: What do you mean by "*i have python path set*"? Why are you typing `cd Python37`? Where are you typing it?

Comment: `cd Python37` is telling your shell to change to the subdirectory named `Python37` in the current working directory. Unless you've done a `cd` to the parent directory that you installed `Python37` in, that's unlikely to do any good.

Comment: You may need to learn a bit more about the basics of using the command line on your platform (presumably Windows?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting PythonPath has nothing to do with your shell finding the `Python37` directory when executing the `cd` command. Adding `Python37` to your PATH variable will also not fix the problem you're having with `cd`. You need to be in the parent directory of your `Python37` directory for the `cd` command to work.

If Python37 directory's location is `C:\Python37` you would have to run cd from the C root directory, like so:

`C:\> cd Python37`

Comment: It worked thanks (sorry for dumb question,im a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your python environment variable is configured correctly, you can run

> python --version

in a terminal window to verify that you're using the correct version.

You can also verify your Environment Variables by going to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables